# Cordova TTS Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, cordova, text-to-speech

have a TTS call that takes an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 
 'then' of undefined.
I understand I should be using a return, but I do not know how to work it in or what I should return

```html
function successCallback(key) {
    hconsole.log('Story for ' + key + ' completed. Adding ' + playing.getItem(key).ctv + ' to past');
    past.addItem(key, playing.getItem(key));
    qpast.addItem(key, playing.getItem(key));
    playing.removeItem(key);
    $('#now-playing').html('<div class="grip"></div>Waiting for next story ...');
    window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Historigin", "Waiting for next story ...", Flag.FLAG_NO_CLEAR);
}

function failureCallback(error) {
    alert(reason);
    hconsole.log('Unable to play story: ' +  JSON.stringify(error));
    hconsole.log('DUDE: ' +  playing.getItem(key).ctv + ' ' +     playing.getItem(key).state + '...' + playing.getItem(key).story);
    queued.addItem(key, playing.getItem(key));
    qpast.removeItem(key);
    past.removeItem(key);
    playing.removeItem(key);
}

if (TTS_ENABLED) {
    hconsole.log('TTS is ENABLED');
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        hconsole.log("WERE SPEAKING");
        window.TTS.speak(playing.getItem(key).ctv + ' ' +       playing.getItem(key).state + ' ' + playing.getItem(key).story).then(successCallback, failureCallback);
    }, false);
} else {
    blah blah blah...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method

```
...
if (TTS_ENABLED) {
    hconsole.log('TTS is ENABLED');
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        hconsole.log("WERE SPEAKING");
        window.TTS.speak(playing.getItem(key).ctv + ' ' +       playing.getItem(key).state + ' ' + playing.getItem(key).story).then(successCallback, failureCallback).catch(failureCallback);
    }, false);
} else {
    blah blah blah...
}
...
```

Also be sure TTS is attached to window

Comment: Hi Isaac.  Thank you for the reply.  I implemented your idea, but get the same result.
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined".
Everything im reading says if the error is "undefined", then my function is not returning a value to the function that called it with something like "return $callingfunctionname;".  So.  is it TTS.speak that needs to return a value upstream to the setInterval function it is contained within?  What if that function starts like this: setInterval(function() { blah blah blah....

Comment: `TTS.speak` returns a void promise which makes `key` in `successCallback(key)` undefined. If `TTS.speak().then()` returns an error, it might be because promise isn't supported being it's a cordova app and you will need to use [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill)